# POSIXct from character returns NA

Tags: r, na, posixct

I have a time in excel that when converter to R, comes as a character and looks someting like this `0.59658.`

I am trying to convert to POSIXct but it returns as a POSIXct with NA.

```
teste <- as.POSIXct(test, format = "%H:%M")
```

I've also tried `teste <- as.POSIXct(test, format = "%H:%M:%S")`
For other columns it works fine, but not this one..

UPDATE: 
I've done the solution, but a second problem comes with the rest of the thing that I need.

```
teste <- as.POSIXct(teste*24*60*60,"%H%M", origin="1970-01-01") 
teste <- format(as.POSIXct(teste, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), format="%H:%M")
```

And now, I want to paste with a date vector that is a POSIXct in the 2013-01-06, with this command:

```
teste<-as.POSIXct(paste(date, teste), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

And the NA are back

Comment: You can perform it in one step using the decimal number for the time and use the date column for the origin: `as.POSIXct(teste*24*60*60,"%H%M", origin=date)`

Answer (score 0):

Confused as to what exactly you want, but what is wrong with this function:

```
df <- data.frame(number = c(0.59658, 0.59658, 0.59658, 0.59658, 0.59658), dates = c("2013-01-06", "2013-01-06", "2013-01-06", "2013-01-07", "2013-01-07"))
testing <- function(number, dates){
  teste <- as.POSIXct(number*24*60*60,"%H%M", origin="1970-01-01") 
  teste <- format(as.POSIXct(teste, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"), format="%H:%M")
  return(as.POSIXct(paste0(dates," ",teste)))
}
```

Which gives the following when doing `testing(df$number, df$dates)`:

```
 "2013-01-06 14:19:00 EST" "2013-01-06 14:19:00 EST" "2013-01-06 14:19:00 EST" "2013-01-07 14:19:00 EST" "2013-01-07 14:19:00 EST"
```

Comment: my date is also a vector with several dates... So I cannot just do a simple paste the date...

Comment: @L8call take a look